# Switch-case is too big

Tags: java, android

Activity that create fragment depends on positon:

```
    private void displayView(int position) {
            try {
                Fragment currentFragment = null;
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                Bundle filter = new Bundle();
                args.putBundle(FragmentSort.FILTER, filter);
                switch (position) {
                    case 1: 
                        currentFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment_A.class.getName());
                        toolbaTitleTextView.setText(getString(R.string.title_AA));
                        filter.putBoolean(Offer.FAVORITE, true);
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        currentFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment_Z.class.getName());
                        toolbaTitleTextView.setText(getString(R.string.title_XX));
                        break;

                       ...
                      case 20:
                        currentFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment_X.class.getName());
                        toolbaTitleTextView.setText(getString(R.string.title_BBB));
                        filter.putBoolean(Offer.DOWNLOADED, true);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                if (currentFragment != null) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    currentFragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentsContainer, currentFragment).commit();
                } else {
                    Debug.e(TAG, "displayView: Error in creating fragment");
                }
            } finally {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
    }
```

As you can see, the activity create fragment depend of **position**. Every fragment has specific set of arguments and specific title.
OK. It's work.

The problem is that `switch-case` is very big.

How can I modify this code to get more readable code?

Maybe use some creation pattern? E.g. `Factory method`?

Comment: Use instances instead of creating 20 different classes?

Comment: @Zoe post as answer.

Comment: I suggest you study about Strategy Pattern

Comment: Not without more code @IntelliJAmiya. If the content of those fragments are 20 different ones, that isn't viable. If/until OP posts more code (to the point where it's possible to write a decent answer) I will

Comment: @guisantogui "Strategy pattern" is a behavior pattern. But I think I need a creation pattern. Is I'm right?

Comment: @Zoe what do you mean?

Comment: @Alex instead of writing 20 different classes, write one and create 20 instances instead where you pass different data based on what the switch case is.

Comment: And what about using the `Fragment` to know those parameter (using an interface to declare the getters), that way, you can get the parameter directly from the instance. All you need to defined is what instance to build based on the `position`.

Comment: Why don't you move the switch code to a single method then separate each case to a method with a Fragment return? Don't overcomplicated your problem by using a pattern for the sake of using a pattern. Break your method to have only 15 lines in the body. It should make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), first define an interface with every values (instance) you need for each case, it could takes parameters if needed.

```
public abstract class FragmentFactory(){
     public abstract Fragment getFragment();
     public abstract Bundle getFilter();
     public abstract String getTooltipText();
}
```

You implement every factory, one per fragment, this can inherite another factory if only one method change, ... this need to be properly analyze.

Then you just need a method to get the factory for the specific `position`.

Using a `List` with every instance

```
public static FragmentFactory getFragment(int position){
    return listFactory.get(position);
}
```

or with a good old switch

```
public static FragmentFactory getFragment(int position){
    switch(position){
    case 1:
         return Factory1;
    case 2:
         return Factory2;
    ...
    default:
         throw new IllegalArgument("No Fragment defined for that position");
}
```

Note that you could simply put the current switch in a `Factory.getFragment(int position)`.

Comment: I believe this isn't an easier solution, rather it is over-engineered and increases coding effort even further.

Comment: @ir2pid Pattern are not only made to render a problem easier but to gave you a more maintainable code. Easier to debug, using a define code with polymorphism. And of course, this is a 5min solution...

Answer (score 1):

Your fragments are all the same? 
Or you have 20 different kinds of fragment?

If **Yes** for my first question:

You should create a list of fragments in your class and instead of using a switch case, you just grab the item inside the list at current position and handle it, like this:

```
    Fragment currentFragment = YOURLISTOFFRAGMENTS.get(position);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    Bundle filter = new Bundle();
    args.putBundle(FragmentSort.FILTER, filter);
...
```

If **No** for my first question and **Yes** for the second, you should do it in a more complicated way, all of your fragments should implement an interface that will have a method, this method implementation may change for each fragment, but should have the same parameters and returns. Then back in your class, you will handle all fragments as the interface declared. Like this

```
public interface HandleName{

    String print()

}


public class MyFrag1 implements HandleName{

    @Override
    public String print(){
        return "MyFrag1"
    }
}


public class MyFrag2 implements HandleName{

    @Override
    public String print(){
        return "MyFrag2"
    }
}
```

And back in your class you should do

```
HandleName interfaceNamedFragment = YOURLISTOFFRAGMENTS.get(position);
interfaceNamedFragment.print()
```

PS: I have not tested this code, but that's the general idea

Comment: Well elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

if it's really necessary, take advantage of the sequential nature of class names and strings.

```
String fragmentString = "Fragment_"+position;
currentFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, fragmentString);
```

for the string use

```
String resourceString = "title_"+position;
int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(resourceString, "string", this.getPackageName());
toolbaTitleTextView.setText(getString(resourceId));
```

You will probably have to transfer the filter settings into the various fragments to make them more specific.

Comment: I would rather use enums than to hope fragments aren't refactor at one point. This could lead to unexpected problem just for a class name.